# Dojo Div Toggle View after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, css, image, dojo

I have 2 divs that are to be hide and visible when i click on the image.I have done that with a combination of dojo and javascript.By default, first time when page loads,the 2 divs will be hide.after that, if i click on the image, the div's are visible.Here my problem is, when i click on any tab in that page, the total page will be refreshed and the div's are becoming invisible. I want those 2 div's are visible even after refreshing the page or moving to the other tab in that page until and unless i click on the image

Here is the my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDivs(){
    console.info("info message");
    if( dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display") == "block"){
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "none");
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "none");
    } else {
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "block");
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "block");
    }
}
</script>

<div class="wpthemeRight" id="foo1" style="display: none">
</div>
<div class="wpthemeBanner" id="foo" style="display: none">
</div>
<div id="ibm-tools" style="display: block;" aria-label="Ibm tools" class="">
<a href="#" onclick="toggleDivs();"><img src="./images/gear.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Please help me in how to proceed to do this.
Thanks in Advance!!!!

I have tried with saving the div state in localstorage but there is no luck

Here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDivState(){
        localStorage["#foo1"] = true;
        f(localStorage["#foo1"] = true)
        {   
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "block");
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "block");
        }
        }
        else
        {
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "none");
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "none");
        }
    }
    </script>
```

And in body,

Answer (score 0):

You can save div state in local storage. for example if you want to save foo1 div state.

```
localStorage["#foo1"] = true;
```

on page load you can check if localStorage["#foo1"] is true and then make the div visible.

(You can view the localStorage in chrome -> F12 (Developer tools) -> Resources -> Local Storage)

---

Your checkDivState function is wrong because localStorage["#foo1"] will be allways true.
let me correct this.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDivs(){
    console.info("info message");
    if( dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display") == "block"){
       localStorage["#foo1"] = false;
       dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "none");
       dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "none");
    } 
    else {
       dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "block");
       dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "block");
       localStorage["#foo1"] = true;
     }
}

function checkDivState(){       
    f(localStorage["#foo1"] = true)
    {   
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "block");
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "block");
    }
    }
    else
    {
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "none");
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "none");
    }
}
```

and call checkDivState on document ready.
Maybe it helps

Comment: I have tried with saving the div state in localstorage but there is no luck

Comment: here is the code: function checkDivState(){
        localStorage["#foo1"] = true;
        f(localStorage["#foo1"] = true)
        {   
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "block");
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "block");
        }
        }
        else
        {
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo'), "display", "none");
            dojo.style(dojo.byId('foo1'), "display", "none");
        }
    }